# Output of void pointer function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have unearthed an old C++ DLL, and I'd like to us it in one of my projects, in VS2015.

The problem is, it does not compile. I got in touch with a guy in the team that made the code in the first place, and he is positive that the exact same code compiled with VS2010.

I have an error in an otherwise very simple function:

Extract of header:

```
/*
Data input
*/
istream* input; //Source of data
long inputpos;  // Current position in the data stream
```

And the code itself:

```
// Helper function to increment a counter while reading a character
void* Calculator::inputstream_get(char& ch)
{
    ++inputpos;
   return input->get(ch);
}
```

In the end, I get an Error  C2440:

```
'return': cannot convert from 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' to 'void *'
```

It is my understanding (I'm not a C++ expert I have to say...) that void pointers could represent any type of data, am I mistaken?

Is there any way to 'cast' my istream to an void pointer?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: _I got in touch with a guy in the team that made the code in the first place, and he is positive that the exact same code compiled with VS2010._ Your guy's statement is correct - it **does** compile with VS2010.

Comment: I get from all of your comments that this is not 'correct' code (as far as VS2015 is concerned).

Why did it compile with VS2010? Has the standard changed?

Thank you for your help

Comment: @Maxime `std::istream` used to define a conversion operator to `void*`, but that's gone in C++11. If you don't want to use C++03, you're going to have to rewrite some code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why this compiles in VS 2010 (C++03) and not in VS 2015 (C++11) is that in C++03, standard library streams defined an implicit conversion to `void*`; the purpose of that conversion was to allow testing them for truthiness (such as `while (cin >> x)`) without allowing an implicit conversion to `bool` (which would allows such monstrosities as `1 + (cin >> x)` to compile).

Note that the *value* of the returned `void*` was underspecified: it was either a null pointer when the stream is in a failed state, or an unspecified non-null pointer when the stram's in good state.

C++11 introduced the notion of explicit conversion operators and contextual conversion to `bool`, which means that these "hacky" conversions to `void*` were replaced in the standard by a safe `explicit operator bool () const`. Of course, this makes the code fail to compile as C++11.

How you can solve this is change `Calculator::inputstream_get` as follows:

```
void* Calculator::inputstream_get(char& ch)
{
   ++inputpos;
   return input->get(ch) ? this : nullptr;
}
```

This preserves the semantics of returning a null pointer on failure, and an unspecified non-null pointer on success.

Comment: Note that the proposed solution is backwards compatible to C++03/VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question. You cannot cast a non pointer to a pointer. But you can cast any pointer to a void pointer with (void*)

Comment: You don't need the cast if you are converting _to_ a void pointer, only if you converting _from_ one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the deal. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

In C++03 that was operator void* and in C++11 that is operator bool.

Change that void* to bool. Note that after the change the code will be not usable in C++03 compiler. You can solve it in a portable fashion with

```
if (input->get(ch)) return true;
else return false;
```

Actually, the most proper way is to return reference to the actual istream object.